# How to create an animated container that hide/show widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, show-hide, animatedcontainer

I wanted to create a `Container` which looks like a `Card` with a small `icon`, when this icon is clicked the container height changed and show different component inside.

[here is the expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXfi3.gif)

Comment: This should probably help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53311403/14394936

Comment: Thank you for your comment bro, the answer bellow was exacty what I wanted, thank you again and happy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working example,

```
  double _height = 50.0;
  bool _isExpanded = false;

  Future<bool> _showList() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 300));
    return true;
  }
```

[AnimatedContainer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html)

```
AnimatedContainer(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      height: _height,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        color: Colors.grey,
      ),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 100,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text('Title'),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    if (!_isExpanded) {
                      setState(() {
                        _height = 300;
                        _isExpanded = true;
                      });
                    } else {
                      setState(() {
                        _height = 50;
                        _isExpanded = false;
                      });
                    }
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    height: 30,
                    width: 40,
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: !_isExpanded ? Icon(Icons.add) : Icon(Icons.remove),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          _isExpanded
              ? FutureBuilder(
                  future: _showList(), /// will wait untill box animation completed
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                      return SizedBox();
                    }
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: 10,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Text('data'); // your custom UI
                      },
                    );
                  })
              : SizedBox.shrink(),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thank you bro and happy coding